# Wordpress Custom Post Type - Rewrite Query

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug

So I have a project I am currently working on, where I have a Wordpress set to a permalink structure of /blog/%postname% for blog posts and pages are domain.com/page-slug/

I have created a custom post type named "portfolio" which has an archive, but also have a page named "portfolio" which pulls the posts in the portfolio custom post type into it.

Now for the slug of the portfolio's I have the custom rewrite set up, as I have to not align with front else the slug would have been /blog/portfolio/postname/ to my custom permalink structure of /blog/postname:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false)
```

Which means the portfolio posts will be /portfolio/post-slug - but the issue is, going to /portfolio/ shows the archive and not the page.

How can I get it to show the portfolio page and not the archive?

Full custom post type function

```
    function rbt_portfolio() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => esc_html_x( 'Portfolios', 'Post Type General Name', 'jstest' ),
        'singular_name'         => esc_html_x( 'Portfolio', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'jstest' ),
        'menu_name'             => esc_html__( 'Portfolio', 'jstest' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => esc_html__( 'Portfolio', 'jstest' ),
        'archives'              => esc_html__( 'Item Archives', 'jstest' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => esc_html__( 'Parent Item:', 'jstest' ),
        'all_items'             => esc_html__( 'All Items', 'jstest' ),
        'add_new_item'          => esc_html__( 'Add New Item', 'jstest' ),
        'add_new'               => esc_html__( 'Add New', 'jstest' ),
        'new_item'              => esc_html__( 'New Item', 'jstest' ),
        'edit_item'             => esc_html__( 'Edit Item', 'jstest' ),
        'update_item'           => esc_html__( 'Update Item', 'jstest' ),
        'view_item'             => esc_html__( 'View Item', 'jstest' ),
        'search_items'          => esc_html__( 'Search Item', 'jstest' ),
        'not_found'             => esc_html__( 'Not found', 'jstest' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => esc_html__( 'Not found in Trash', 'jstest' ),
        'featured_image'        => esc_html__( 'Featured Image', 'jstest' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => esc_html__( 'Set featured image', 'jstest' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => esc_html__( 'Remove featured image', 'jstest' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => esc_html__( 'Use as featured image', 'jstest' ),
        'inserbt_into_item'     => esc_html__( 'Insert into item', 'jstest' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => esc_html__( 'Uploaded to this item', 'jstest' ),
        'items_list'            => esc_html__( 'Items list', 'jstest' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => esc_html__( 'Items list navigation', 'jstest' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => esc_html__( 'Filter items list', 'jstest' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => esc_html__( 'Portfolio', 'jstest' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail'),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-index-card',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false),
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rbt_portfolio', 0 );
```

Comment: If you do not need the archive, could you set `'has_archive' => false`?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee disabling 'has_archive' => false seem to then only show the blog post archive instead of the page that is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get it to show the portfolio page and not the archive?

1. As pointed in the comments, just set `has_archive` to `false`.
2. But after that, be sure to flush the rewrite rules - just visit the permalink settings admin page.